# jade and java script - display element with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i am trying to display element only when the selling price is bigger than 0

this is my code

```
.basket-sidebar-right-body-basket-why-not-try
      .item-grid-item(dynamic-position, data-rv-each-item='model:suggested', data-rv-on-click='view.attemptToAddItemToCart')
            .item-title(data-rv-text='item.WebTitle | startCase')
            .item-image(focusable)
                  img(focusable,data-rv-src='item.ImageUrl', onerror='this.src = "http://placehold.it/237x140";')
                  .why-not-try-text= strings.whyNotTry
                  .why-not-try-price
                       span.currency-symbol &pound;
                       span.price(data-rv-text='item.SellingPrice | asCurrency')
```

i am trying to display the why not try price only when item.sellingPrice is bigger than 0

anyone know how i can do that
?

Comment: i have tried but it didnt work
can you show me how

Comment: data-rv-if(item.sellingPrice > 0)

Comment: Why not simple if: http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/

Comment: tried that but it didnt help (and it looks ugly)